# Upload a File with Rest Sharp from an Azure Blob Sorage Source

Tags: azure, upload, blob, restsharp

i got the following rest sharp function for upload an local file to an rest endpoint, but i would like to reference an http source from blob storage (with SASS instead) ?

```
request.AddFile("file", "c:\temp\test.txt");
```

to

```
request.AddFile("file", "http://azure.blob/testblob/test.txt");
```

is that possible ?

thx

Answer (score 0):

**`NO`**,I don't think it is possible, you need to download the file from blob storage and then upload.